# Emulating a button push or a mouse click with Mathematica code

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, button

I need to perform a long action with a button. I tried setting the `DynamicEvaluationTimeout`, but it seems it doesn't work for me. So I want to try using several buttons to compute pieces of the whole task and here's where my problem starts:
How to tell *Mathematica* that a button should be pressed (or have its action performed) without actually pressing the button by user? Is there a way to emulate such a thing from within the code?
I need to use the preemptive link, so `Method -> "Queued"` is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica*.SE! Could you please post a working minimal example of your case?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: You may find this thread relevant: [How to Initiate a queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19174/89).

Comment: @Daroslav: can you explain why you (think you) need the preemptive link?  If your calculation takes time, using the queued link seems to be your best choice. From what you write I'm not convinced that what you need can't be done with `Method->"Queued"`. I think you should explain better what you try to do and why -- probably without preemptively excluding possible solutions. And remember: providing an example (especially if it demonstrates what does not work) for people to play with will always help a lot to get better answers.

Answer (score 5):

One can come up with some messy method to evaluate a front-end button programmatically, but I think it is easier to separate the button functionality from the button itself, as `listenerButtonFunction[]`. Here I introduce a timer button that, if pushed, counts down simulating a long calculation. When it finishes, it switches the flag `active` to `True`. The second button has a `Dynamic` wrapper and thus it listens to the changes made to `active`: whenever `active` is set to `True`, the appearance of the listener button is changed. Now the functionality of the listener button is separated, so we can call it right after setting `active = True` in the first button, simulating the manual push of the listener button.

Note that I only used `Method -> "Queued"` to see how the timer goes down. If omitted, the listener still will be activated in due time. Also, the listener button can be pushed on its own.

```
active = False;
n = 0;
listenerButtonFunction[] := Print["Listener activated"];
Row@{Button["Timer", active = False; n = 100; 
   Do[Pause[.02]; n = n - 1, {i, 100}]; active = True; 
   listenerButtonFunction[], Method -> "Queued"], Spacer@5, Dynamic@n}
Dynamic@If[active,
  Button["Listener: ACTIVE", active = False, 
   Appearance -> {Automatic, "Pressed"}],
  Button["Listener: inactive", listenerButtonFunction[], 
   Appearance -> Automatic]
  ]
```

[image]

### Update

The following method creates a button that is wrapped in `Dynamic` that listens to the state change of the switch `active`, which can be changed by either hitting the second button or waiting for the calculation of the first button to finish (just like above). The function of this second button is actually performed by the `Dynamic` wrapper whenever `active` becomes `True`. The `Print` statement is redirected by default to the **Messages** window, but if `listenerFunction` is e.g. a long calculation that does not print anything, this shouldn't matter.

```
active = False; n = 0;
listenerFunction[] := Print["Listener pushed"];

Row@{Button["First", active = False; n = 100; 
   Do[Pause[.005]; n = n - 1, {i, 100}]; active = True;, 
   Method -> "Queued"], Spacer@5, Dynamic@n}

Dynamic[If[active, listenerFunction[]]; 
 Button[If[active, "active", "inactive"], active = ! active]]
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but I can't see it working for me.

Comment: @Daroslav Where does it fail? Perhaps set the `Pause` value to something smaller? Make sure that you evaluate it with a fresh kernel.

Comment: I'm sorry, I pressed enter too soon. Here's the rest of my comment:

I want to use my button to run an animation with a dynamic `Graphics` object. Since it's long, the preemptive link times out. The good news is, I can split it into parts. So I need a `Button`, that will do a part of the job, and then calls itself (or a different `Button`) to do a part of the rest of the job, and so on.

Comment: @Daros You could put the "rest of the job" into `listenerButtonFunction`, and you can link an infinite number of buttons in this way.

Comment: I just thought I could, guess I needed some time to digest your idea ;)
Thanks, that's really helpful, I'll try to adapt that.

Comment: Well, I tried to implement it, but as far as I understand what your code does is simply trigger the `listenerButtonFunction` with two different buttons: timer and dynamic. Timer button calls it and changes the appearance of the dynamic button, but it does not force that dynamic button to evaluate the function.

Comment: @Daroslav I've manufactured another way to set up a listener. Please check whether it fits your needs.