# How to Initiate a queued evaluation from a Dynamic GUI without using a Button

Tags: dynamic, button

I have a `Dynamic`-based GUI, and one part of it will kick off a calculation that could take longer than the default 5-second dynamic timeout.

I know that `Button` has a `Method -> "Queued"` option for performing an evaluation on the main link rather than by doing a pre-emptive evaluation.

How can I initiate a main link evaluation without requiring the user to click a button?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you pass `SynchronousUpdating->False` to `Dynamic`, it will perform operations on the main link.  Note that this only works where `Dynamic` is displayed as a typeset result (i.e., typeset as a `DynamicBox`).  It does not presently work where `Dynamic` is used to give a value to a control (such as `Slider`) or an option.

A quick survey of other constructs...

`ActionMenu` has a `Method` option which works identically to `Button`.

`EventHandler`, as of version 9, has no way to do main link evaluations.

(Edit: As of v10, the `EventHandler` and the various `EventHandler`-like options now accept a `Method` option.)

`FrontEndDynamicExpression` and friends, as of version 9, have no way to do main link evaluations.

Comment: "It does not presently work where Dynamic is used to give a value to a control (such as Slider) or an option." it this somewhere in docs?

Answer (score 16):

While John Fultz gave a depressing answer concerning GUI controls, I doubted that this cannot be done in *Mathematica*. A bit of exploration and Rojo's [extremely useful answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19821/89) helped me to come up with a workaround to simulate `Method -> Queued` for GUI controllers other than `Button`.

The function `queued` accepts any dynamic controller as its first argument and any command as its second argument and whenever dynamic manipulation of the controller is done, it fires the command just like `Button[..., Method -> "Queued"]` would do:

```
Attributes[queued] = {HoldRest};
queued[gui_, action_] := DynamicModule[{trigger = False},
   DynamicWrapper[EventHandler[gui,
     {"MouseDown" :> (trigger = False), 
      "MouseDragged" :> (trigger = False), 
      "MouseUp" :> (trigger = True)},
     PassEventsDown -> True, PassEventsUp -> False],
    If[trigger, Refresh[action, None]], SynchronousUpdating -> False
    ]];
```

Now simulate a long calculation that depends on a slider-value and wrap the whole in `queued`. Whenever the `Slider` is released, the updating of the long calculation starts:

```
long[x_] := Module[{a = .3}, Do[a = x a (1 - a), {i, 10^6}]];
active = False; x = 3.5;
queued[Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 4}, Appearance -> "Labeled"], 
   active = True; long@x; active = False;]
Dynamic@If[active, ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10^6}], "Ready."]
```

[image]

Just for reference, the same cannot be done with the second argument of `Dynamic` (as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22255/89)). This won't work:

```
Slider@Dynamic[x, {(x = #) &, active = True; long@x; active = False;}]
```

### Update

Concerning `ContinuousAction -> False`, my problem is twofold: first, it does not update the controller variable continuously (which is an unnecessary limitation in my case), second, the following code won't work as expected:

```
trigger = False; x = 3.5;
Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; trigger = True; long[x]; trigger = False;) &], {1, 4}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False, Appearance -> "Labeled"]
Dynamic@If[trigger, ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10^6}], "Ready."]
```

Neither does this:

```
trigger = False; x = 3.5;
DynamicWrapper[Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; trigger = True;) &], {1, 4}, 
  ContinuousAction -> False, Appearance -> "Labeled"], 
 If[trigger, Refresh[long[x]; trigger = False;, None]]]
Dynamic@If[trigger, ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10^6}], "Ready."]
```

Comment: I think that there is a somewhat simpler way to achieve the same: You can use as the first argument to the `DynamicWrapper` something like the following: `Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; trigger = True) &], {1, 4}, ContinuousAction -> False, Appearance -> "Labeled"]`. This is not only somewhat simpler, it also will work with gui elements which are not triggered by the mouse, as e.g. `InputField`...

Comment: @Albert Please see edit about my problems with your proposed solution. Concerning those gui elements that are not mouse-driven, one can easily modify the underlying `EventHandler` to handle those.

Comment: I now see that it was not enough to just post that fragment to get the correct behavior. I think the complete solution does work as you want, but I needed to add some to make the controller variable change continuously. As this is now too long for just a comment I added an extra answer...

Answer (score 10):

Based on Istvans solution this should do the same thing, but is somewhat simpler in that it avoids the `EventHandler` which would need adoption to match the possible interactions of the gui element used. The use of the three "change functions" also makes possible to continuously update the controller variable but only trigger the long calculation when the "editing" is finished:

```
long[x_] := Module[{a = .3}, Do[a = x a (1 - a), {i, 10^6}]]
x = 3.5; active = False;
DynamicModule[{trigger = False},
 Column[{
   DynamicWrapper[
    Slider[
     Dynamic[x, {(x = #) &, (x = #) &, (x = #; trigger = True) &}],
     {1, 4}, ContinuousAction -> True, Appearance -> "Labeled"
     ],
    If[trigger, 
     Refresh[active = True; long@x; active = False; trigger = False;, 
      None]],
    SynchronousUpdating -> False
    ],
   Dynamic@If[active, ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10^6}], "Ready."]
   }]
 ]
```

This should work just as well for e.g. an `InputField`:

```
long[x_] := Module[{a = .3}, Do[a = x a (1 - a), {i, 10^6}]]
x = 3.5; active = False;
DynamicModule[{trigger = False},
 Column[{
   DynamicWrapper[
    InputField[
     Dynamic[x, {(x = #) &, (x = #) &, (x = #; trigger = True) &}],
     Number, ContinuousAction -> False
     ],
    If[trigger, 
     Refresh[active = True; long@x; active = False; trigger = False;, 
      None]],
    SynchronousUpdating -> False
    ],
   Dynamic@If[active, ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10^6}], "Ready."]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: +1 Marvellous! This should be part of *Mathematica* 10, in the form of `Slider[..., Method -> "Queued"]` and similar for all gui controls. I was about to aim for solving {$f_{start}$, $f$, $f_{end}$}, but this is now handled beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this inside a `Manipulate`. Two useful settings are:

```
SynchronousUpdating -> False
```

and

```
ContinuousAction -> False
```

which apply to any of the possible control types (including sliders). The first specifies "whether or not contents are evaluated synchronously" and the second specifies whether an "action should be taken continuously while controls are moved". The latter is something like Istvan's queued slider.